# Hidden NGINX rewrite URL segments into query string for PHP

Tags: php, magento, nginx

I'm using Magento and I have this string:
/rims/mercedes-benz/e-class/w211

And I would like for when a user visits:
'site.com/rims/mercedes-benz/e-class/w211' for PHP (Magento) to process the URL as:
/rims?brand=mercedes-benz&model=e-class&type=w211

I don't want to redirect the user, they will still see the exact URL they went to, but just for PHP to process the parameters broken down into query strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this by creating your own Router for the frontName rims, then you can do pretty much whatever you want with the params in the url.

To do this you need to register your router in the config.xml of your module like this:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <your_module>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <frontName>rims</frontName>
                <module>Your_Module</module>
            </args>
        </your_module>
    </routers>
```

Then in Your_Module folder under Controllers (notice the upper case C) add a Router.php file, like this:

```
class Your_Module_Controller_Router extends Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard {

    public function match(Zend_Controller_Request_Http $request) {
        // add the logic to deal with params here
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. What I did differently though was to name the folder 'Controller' and I had to set the config of my module to use the new route controller.
Thanks!